# Getting an empty dataframe after splitting my dataset back into train and test datasets

Tags: python, pandas

First I used:

```
train['source']='train' 
test['source']='test'
data = pd.concat([train,test],ignore_index=True)
```

2. Performed data exploration,cleaning on fulldata and now I wanted to split them back into train and test datsets.

I used the following code :

```
#Divide into test and train:
train = data.loc[data['source']=="train"]
test = data.loc[data['source']=="test"]
```

But after doing so train and test datasets are empty dataframes giving just column names. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: It maybe be because you are using `data` instead of `fulldata` while dividing them

Comment: Sorry I mispelled it while posting the question. But the problem still persists even after that!!!

Comment: You sure `fulldata.loc[fulldata['source']=="train"]` than  `fulldata.loc[data['source']=="train"]`

Comment: Actually I originally used "data"(not " full data") in my original code. But for the community to understand it i just replaced it with full data. Let me rephrase the whole question again. Then plzz help me with my problem. :)

Comment: Can you add the sample of `train` and `test`

Comment: Well if I create a sample test and train dataframes its working for me. There might be a typo too in your approach check once.

Comment: Yes @Dark... working for me now.. There was a bracket typo. Thanks for helping out :)